# unable to upsert Account with different owner in same transaction

Tags: integration, soap-api

I am using SOAPUI to post an XML.
I have the below XML code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:OwnerChangeOptions>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <urn:options>
            <urn:type>KeepAccountTeam</urn:type>
            <urn:execute>1</urn:execute>
         </urn:options>
      </urn:OwnerChangeOptions>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId></urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
<urn:upsert>
<urn:externalIDFieldName>SAP_No__c</urn:externalIDFieldName>
<urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Account">
<urn1:SAP_No__c>006851xxx</urn1:SAP_No__c>
<urn1:Customer_Service_Z6__r>
<urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>DExx</urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>
</urn1:Customer_Service_Z6__r>
<urn1:Owner>
<urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>00000xxxx</urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>
</urn1:Owner>
<urn1:Sales_Rep_SAP_Z1__r>
<urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>00000xxxx</urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>
</urn1:Sales_Rep_SAP_Z1__r>
</urn:sObjects>
<urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Account">
<urn1:SAP_No__c>00532xxxx</urn1:SAP_No__c>
<urn1:Customer_Service_Z6__r>
<urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>SKxx</urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>
</urn1:Customer_Service_Z6__r>
<urn1:Owner>
<urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>V2xxxxx</urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>
</urn1:Owner>
<urn1:Sales_Rep_SAP_Z1__r>
<urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>V253xxx</urn1:SAP_User_Id__c>
</urn1:Sales_Rep_SAP_Z1__r>
</urn:sObjects>
</urn:upsert>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am getting the following response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <LimitInfoHeader>
         <limitInfo>
            <current>20018</current>
            <limit>5000000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
         </limitInfo>
      </LimitInfoHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <upsertResponse>
         <result>
            <created>false</created>
            <errors>
               <fields>OwnerId</fields>
               <message>All accounts must have the same current owner and new owner.</message>
               <statusCode>INVALID_FIELD</statusCode>
            </errors>
            <id>0013N0xxx0pnZxxxAU</id>
            <success>false</success>
         </result>
         <result>
            <created>false</created>
            <errors>
               <fields>OwnerId</fields>
               <message>All accounts must have the same current owner and new owner.</message>
               <statusCode>INVALID_FIELD</statusCode>
            </errors>
            <id>0013N00xxxxoQAI</id>
            <success>false</success>
         </result>
      </upsertResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please let me know for any solution to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Since ownership changes can cause expensive recalculations, this restriction keeps that calculation down to a reasonable time frame. You will need to break up your updates such that the constraint is observed. In other words, reach set of records must belong to the same user and be transferred to the same new owner.